# JACK, PulseAudio and Firefox: Enable JACK for firefox in the near future

Tags: firefox, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

Firefox bug #1345661 was closed with "WONTFIX", which certainly will break my current setup in the near future (I play firefox sound through `alsa_in`:`loopback`->JACK). I have read that Firefox has JACK support now, though it is not yet stable. Questions:

1. Will JACK support in Firefox be officially supported?
2. Will Ubuntu enable JACK support in Firefox before raw ALSA support ends?

I the answer is No No, how can I reliable restore functionality without breaking JACK? It is possible to run PA through `alsa_in`, but I guess that would introduce some extra latency, break AV sync, or introduce signal distortion due to multiple resamplers.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following script I call "pulsejack".  Call it without arguments and it connects an existing `jackd` to PulseAudio.  Called with any arguments, it starts up `jackd` with those arguments and then connects it to PulseAudio.  Firefox can pick up from PulseAudio then.

```bsh
#/bin/sh
if [ $# -gt 1 ]
then
    killall jackd 2> /dev/null && sleep 2
    jackd "$@" && sleep 2
fi
pactl load-module module-jack-sink channels=2
pactl load-module module-jack-source channels=2
pacmd set-default-sink jack_out
pacmd set-default-source jack_in
```

You may need to run
`sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-jack`
in order to get the respective modules.

Comment: The interest of that answer is that it shows a way. But that interest is tampered by the fact that the recommended way to run jack, is without pulseaudio, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I've compiled mozilla-central firefox with jack support and output (sources) Automatically get created when you visit a site with audio (i.e youtube).

However - input sink sources do not get created ; I don't see them appear in cadence/jack patch bay. So anything that relies on Mic input fails. i.e meet.jit.si / webrtc tests...

---

Another problem is that even using the pulseaudio bridge ; the same issue input sources even when connected correctly to the pulse-sink don't get recognized by firefox. In Chrome however Mic input correctly uses the plugged capture to pulse-sink. So I think this is a firefox bug in the way it detects and reports Mic presence information.

My personal view is that the Input/capture sink sources should be created on firefox start up rather than on a per-tab/site basis as with the output sources in the jack only case.

Comment: Mic presence detection? In the old days, there was no such thing. It was always "present" as an input jack on the soundcard, and it still is, on more professional stuff. Mine has 2 XLR connectors that can be used as either line or mic depending on gain. For JACK, it should just create input ports.

Comment: in firefox/adobe flash.  hardware devices (alsa) only are detected. in chrome/pepperflash  software devices (pulse and loopback) are also detected. I'm not sure what causes the difference.