# Errors starting qjackctl

Tags: sound, jack

I start `qjackctl` and see this:

[image: qjackctl]

[image: Connections]
The RT is blinking, so good there. No audio though, e.g. on YouTube in a browser.
Below is the text in Messages window when starting `qjackctl`

It looks like jack is not running so it then starts it. Do I need to explicitly start jack (or is it best to) before running qjackctl?

Then there are some error messages:

```
    Tue Jul 14 17:01:01 2020: ERROR: Cannot lock down 82280346 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Tue Jul 14 17:01:01 2020: ERROR: control open "hw:USB" (No such device)
Tue Jul 14 17:01:01 2020: ERROR: ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for capture. Falling back to playback-only mode
Tue Jul 14 17:01:01 2020: ERROR: Cannot use real-time scheduling (RR/10)(1: Operation not permitted)
Tue Jul 14 17:01:01 2020: ERROR: AcquireSelfRealTime error
Cannot lock down 82280346 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
```

Do any of these need to be addressed?

```
17:04:32.446 Statistics reset.
17:04:32.451 ALSA connection change.
17:04:32.479 D-BUS: Service is available (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
17:04:32.516 D-BUS: JACK server is starting...
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
17:04:32.539 D-BUS: JACK server was started (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Tue Jul 14 17:04:32 2020: Starting jack server...
Tue Jul 14 17:04:32 2020: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Tue Jul 14 17:04:32 2020: self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
Tue Jul 14 17:04:32 2020: ERROR: Cannot lock down 82280346 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Tue Jul 14 17:04:32 2020: ERROR: control open "hw:USB" (No such device)
Tue Jul 14 17:04:32 2020: Acquired audio card Audio2
Tue Jul 14 17:04:32 2020: creating alsa driver ... hw:PCH|hw:USB|128|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
Tue Jul 14 17:04:32 2020: ERROR: ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for capture. Falling back to playback-only mode
Tue Jul 14 17:04:32 2020: configuring for 44100Hz, period = 128 frames (2.9 ms), buffer = 2 periods
Tue Jul 14 17:04:32 2020: ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
Tue Jul 14 17:04:32 2020: ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
Tue Jul 14 17:04:32 2020: ERROR: Cannot use real-time scheduling (RR/10)(1: Operation not permitted)
Tue Jul 14 17:04:32 2020: ERROR: AcquireSelfRealTime error
Tue Jul 14 17:04:32 2020: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_1'
Tue Jul 14 17:04:32 2020: New client 'system' with PID 0
Tue Jul 14 17:04:32 2020: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_2'
Tue Jul 14 17:04:34 2020: Saving settings to "/home/mickeydog/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
17:04:34.735 JACK connection change.
17:04:34.736 Server configuration saved to "/home/mickeydog/.jackdrc".
17:04:34.736 Statistics reset.
17:04:34.739 Client activated.
17:04:34.740 Patchbay deactivated.
17:04:34.756 JACK connection graph change.
Cannot lock down 82280346 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Tue Jul 14 17:04:34 2020: New client 'qjackctl' with PID 3514
```

-- Edit --
After setting Input Device, errors are:

```
Wed Jul 15 07:55:00 2020: ERROR: Cannot lock down 82280346 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Wed Jul 15 07:55:00 2020: ERROR: Cannot use real-time scheduling (RR/10)(1: Operation not permitted)
Wed Jul 15 07:55:00 2020: ERROR: AcquireSelfRealTime error
```

With respect to limits, there is a file in `/etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf.disabled` which contains:

```
@audio   -  rtprio     95
@audio   -  memlock    unlimited
#@audio   -  nice      -19
```

There is also a file `/etc/security/limits.conf` in which all the lines are commented out, i.e. start with #

Here is the system Sound Settings after starting PulseAudio. If PulseAudio is not running, there is nothing in the Output tab.

[image: Settings]

I tried this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -p high jackd
```

which seems to have no effect

The last 3 errors were removed by changing the name of `audio.conf.disabled`:

```
cd etc/security/limits.d
sudo cp audio.conf.disabled audio.conf
sudo rm audio.conf.disabled
```

QasMixer:

[image: QasMixer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- No need to start  jackd before qjackctl ,but it is possible  f.i.
  `jackd -d alsa -d hw:0  &`
- You have bad setting in qjackctl advanced audio config :
  hw:PCH for play (this is ok) ,  but hw:USB for record ,
  hw:USB does not exists : `ERROR: control open "hw:USB" (No such device)`):
  Usually 1st audio device is `hw:0` ,
  2nd audio device is `hw:1`
  (Or may be you removed USB device after saving configuration?)
- Realtime scheduling error may be caused by previous error, or by missing the modification to the limits.conf for your user, [see here](https://jackaudio.org/faq/linux_rt_config.html).
- no sound in Firefox or Chrome: normal as they use pulseaudio which is disabled (i guess) .  Using jackd and pulseaudio is possible but first jackd must be ok .
- For the midi , try to connect input to output by selecting one client on each side  and click "connect"

Comment: added midi and Firefox

Comment: How do I set the audio device to hw:0? Yes I disabled pulseaudio. Is it not possible to use just jack for everything? A couple years ago there was talk of [jack for firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/923990/jack-pulseaudio-and-firefox-enable-jack-for-firefox-in-the-near-future). I have a MIDI keyboard that I want to use. (Akai MPK Mini).

Comment: In Settings > Advanced > Input Device, I set it to `hw:PCH,0`. I don't see just `hw:0` or `hw:1`. Is this correct? It eliminated a couple errors (see edit)

Comment: hw:PCH,0 is ok. for the realtime error, try to rename audio.conf.disabled to audio.conf (and reboot) , you must also be in audio group

Comment: I renamed the file (see above) and get no errors now. Still no sound though. What do I need to do to 'be in audio group"?

Comment: no error means realtime is ok, so you are in the group. Test audio (not midi)  using audacity or ardour or vlc , configured to  jackd in audio settings . Check in qjackctl "connections" audio .   For midi , you need fluidsynth to connect to the midi keyboard ., see  http://tedfelix.com/linux/linux-midi.html#qjackctl

Comment: and you must use alsamixer to set volume (or alsa mixer with gui: qasmixer )

Comment: Ok I got QasMixer, set it as above. No change. What should I set?

Comment: HDMI audio  is useless,  select Intel HDA or the usb device  (if it is a real usb device ) , check  volume in  Qasmixer, and check audio tab in qjackctl connection (you must see audio apps using jack here : Ardour etc ...)

Comment: will post another question. This is a nightmare.

Comment: For  musical use, Ubuntu Studio should beeasier as jackd is preinstaled

Comment: To use Ubuntu Studio, do i have to completely reinstall the new operating system? I currently have Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: Currently downloading Ubuntu Studio..It looks like I have the choice of keeping the existing data or not.